# Design a generic trait in Scala

Tags: scala, generics, traits

I'm learning data structure recently. There is a case that I want to design a generic trait which type should support comparable. If I need to design a generic class, I can design like the following:

```
class SortedType [A: Ordering](val x: A)
val x = new SortedType(3)
val y = new SortedType("Hello, World!")
```

However, since in scala, the trait can't have parameters with context bounds, so I can't define a trait like this `trait SortedType[A: Ordering]`. How can I design the trait so that it's generic type support comparable?
Thanks for your generous advice!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The constraint `[A: Ordering]` does not tell anything about the type `A` itself. Instead, it specifies that an (implicitl) instance of type `Ordering[A]` exists. The simplest way to guarantee the existence of an instance of type `Ordering[A]` is to simply provide a method `def ord: Ordering[A]`.

So, you could make the ordering into a member of the `trait`, then accept an ordering as factory-method parameter:

```
trait SortedStuff[A] {
  def ord: Ordering[A]
  def x: A
}

object SortedStuff {
  def apply[A: Ordering](a: A) = new SortedStuff[A] {
    def ord = implicitly
    def x = a
  }
}
```

Note that this only makes sense if `SortedStuff` is some kind of module that is supposed to operate on a whole bunch of `A`s. Attaching an `Ordering` to separate elements of `A` does not make any sense - ordering is a relation *between* elements, not a property of each single isolated element.